# The ring Z/pZ[Z/pZ] (p is a prime) is not a semi-simple ring.

Tags: ring-theory

A ring A is semi-simple if and only if it is Artinian and radical(intersection of all of its maximal ideal) of A is zero.
As the ring Z/pZ[Z/pZ] is finite,so it is Artinian.So now it is enough to show that radical of Z/pZ[Z/pZ] is non-zero.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: By "Z/pZ[Z/pZ]" do you mean the group ring over the additive group Z/pZ by the field Z/pZ? Or something else?

Comment: By Z/pZ[Z/pZ] I mean group ring over the additive group Z/pZ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think(?) you're talking about $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)[G]$ where $G$ is the cyclic group of order $p$.

As you commented, it's surely an Artinian ring, but it's also commutative. Commutative semisimple rings have to be finite products of fields, and those don't have any nilpotent elements.

It's easy to check that $x=\sum_{g\in G} g$ is a nonzero nilpotent element. (It squares to zero.)

You might be interested in looking up [Maschke's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maschke%27s_theorem) which tells us when group rings over finite rings are semisimple.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I want to prove radical of Z/pZ[Z/pZ] is non-zero.Do you have any idea how to show this?

Comment: @RipanSaha A nilpotent element in a commutative ring is always in the Jacobson radical, so I already gave you my idea.

Comment: yes I got it now...Thank you @rschwieb